# How would I write the schema for the following XML code? (Restricting values)

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd, schema, restriction

XML instance:

```
<scooters>
    <scooter id = "1">
        <name>Razer </name>
        <description> A powerful scooter </description>
    </scooter>
    <scooter id = "2">
        <name>Apex</name>
        <description> Another good scooter </description>
    </scooter>
</scooters>
```

XML schema element declarations:

```
<xsd:element name = "scooters">

    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name = "scooter">
                <xsd:complexType>

         <!-- How do I put validation on the above field considering that 
              it is a complexType (i think), and that it needs to be a number 
              between 0 and 50? -->

                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name = "name" type = "xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name = "description" />
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base = "xsd:string">
                                <xsd:enumeration value = "Great" />
                                <xsd:enumeration value = "Old" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:element>
```

Can someone please help me identify any errors in my code? as well as tell me how to validate the `id` field to between `0` and `50`?

Thanks very much in advance,
Mark

Also, just a random question, does anyone know an advantage of using *xml namespaces* when there arent any name conflicts? has it got something to do with reusing the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

please use this XML schema corrected :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="scooters">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="scooter" maxOccurs="50" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="id" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

please use : `< maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">` in order to validate the field between min and max.

Using namespaces allows you to make import and include functions that would allow you to reuse the XML SCHEMA in other XML SCHEMA. :)

please consider taking a look at this very good article : [XML 10 recommandations](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/11/07/ten-practical-recommendations-for-designing-and-building-highly-reusable-xml-schemas/)

Tell me if everything's all right. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking your schema, there are some errors. For example, you can't have `<xsd:simpleType>` as a child of `<xsd:sequence>`. You *could* place it as the simple type of `description`:

```
<xsd:element name = "description">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base = "xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value = "Great" />
            <xsd:enumeration value = "Old" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

That would fix the schema. But I don't think you would want that. It would not validate your XML instance because only the values `Great` or `Old` could be used in `<description>`.

So I will assume your *instance* contains the data you want to validate, and suggest some changes to the XSD based on it.

The *complex type* is basically a type which may contain *groups* of elements (sequences, choices, etc.). If your type is a *string* or anything you could represent as a string (such as a number, a date), then you would use a *simple type*. But if you have attributes, then you must use a complex type. In this case, you can declare an element with a complex type but with *simple content*. Attributes are always simple types.

In your case you have two elements which are complex types: `<scooters>` and `<scooter>`. Both contain sequences:

```
<xsd:element name = "scooters">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
    ...

<xsd:element name = "scooter">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
    ...
```

The two others are simple types that use *native* XSD string types, and are part of the sequence declared in `scooter`. Sequences enforce an order, so you must always place `name` before `description`:

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Your `scooters` element should allow multiple `scooter` children. You can add the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute to allow any number of child `<scooter>` elements:

```
<xsd:element name = "scooter" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

The *default* for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` is always 1. You can make an element *optional* using `minOccurs="0"`.

Finally the `<xsd:attribute>` declaration should appear as a *child* of `<xsd:complexType>` and *after* the `<xsd:sequence>`. If you didn't have any restrictions you could simply declare it as an `xsd:integer`:

```
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:integer">
```

To *restrict* that integer to the values between 0 and 50, you need to add a `<xsd:restriction>`:

```
<xsd:attribute name="id">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="50"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
```

This is your final XSD with all the fixes. It now validates your instance:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xsd:element name = "scooters">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name = "scooter" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>

                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>

                        <xsd:attribute name="id">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                                    <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="50"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:attribute>

                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>

            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

You could also declare some types and element as children of `<xsd:schema>`. This can be a matter of style but it also allows your types and elements to be reused (e.g.: you might want to define a type with restriction for certain attributes based on some regular expression and reuse it with other elements). Here is your schema with two elements and your attribute type as top-level structures. Note that the `scooters` declaration uses a `ref` element to reference the `scooter` declaration.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xsd:element name = "scooters">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="scooter" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="scooter">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="IdType"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:simpleType name="IdType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="50"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```